# Update content programmatically

Tags: typo3

I am publishing content on a TYPO3 instance where I have just editor rights. At the moment, that content is generated automatically as HTML; my workflow consists of

1. Copy HTML code
2. Log in to TYPO3
3. Select page
4. Click Edit on the HTML element of this page
5. Paste HTML code
6. Submit

Is there a library or an API that helps automating this process?

Comment: To all the downvoters: Can you explain how this question could be improved?

Comment: I guess the downvoters don't like the way you're using the CMS to just paste HTML code to a HTML CE and maybe they don't like that you didn't think of a concept yourself first. But maybe you just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only an normal editor in your TYPO3 instance, I assume you cannot just add a TYPO3 extensions that helps you with the task. If you could alter the TYPO3 instance, there would be numerous ways to automate the process: A Scheduler task that fetches new content and puts it to a page or even fetches content from a mailbox or Dropbox share etc..

The only solution I see is that you do some browser automation to perform this task. You use e.g. use [Chromium Browser Automation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-browser-automati/jmbmjnojfkcohdpkpjmeeijckfbebbon) if you work with Chrome. You can record all form entries (username, password, paste text to RTE) and clicks and you also should be able to define some variables (ID of the page and content element, content itself).